# fscanf array pointer array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf

I need help for this situation

I want with the method `ReadFile()` with `fscanf` directly write the values from the file in my array `table[]` in main.

Can anyone help ?

```
int main() {
  float table[] = {1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 10.0};
  ReadFile(&table);
  printf(/*...print table at this point...*/)
}

void ReadFile(float (*P)[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  int i;

  // Exists? 
  fp = fopen("results.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  // read file 
  fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n", (&P)[0], (&P)[1], (&P)[2], (&P)[3],
      (&P)[4]);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand what means `float (*P)[]`.

In 2 words it means a pointer to an array of floats with out bounds. Actually,
it's just a pointer to a pointer to float value.

And in your scanf line:

```c
fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n",(&P)[0],(&P)[1],(&P)[2],(&P)[3],(&P)[4]);
```

Your are taking an address of a pointer which points to an array of floats and you are shifting address by 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (Depends on argument).

So you are assigning float value to a pointer. Not to a float variable.

To fix it, you can dereference P instead of taking address:

```c
fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n", &(*P)[0], &(*P)[1], &(*P)[2], &(*P)[3], &(*P)[4]);
```

So in this line we are dereferencing P by operation *P. So now we got a pointer to float (when P is a pointer to pointer to float). With operation (*P)[0] we are incrementing pointer with 0. so now it will point to `(address + 0)` element. And after it we dereferencing it and getting the value of the 0 element.
So basically `(*P)[0]` is the same as `*(*P + 0)`.
But since we don't need a value but the address of the element, we are using operator & to get it. So finally, we get `&(*P)[0]` which equals to `&*(*P + 0)` or just `(*P + 0)`.

To make it simple, we can use just a pointer to float in function parameters.

```cpp
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ReadFile(float *P) { 
        FILE *fp; 
        int i;

        fp = fopen("results.txt","r"); 

        if (fp == NULL) {
                perror("failed to open file");
                return;
        }

        // read file 
        fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n", &P[0], &P[1], &P[2], &P[3], &P[4]);

        fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
        float table[] = {1.0,2.0,4.0,8.0,10.0}; 

        ReadFile(table);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]); ++i)
                printf("%f ", table[i]);
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

You can compare these 2 lines:

```cpp
fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n", &(*P)[0], &(*P)[1], &(*P)[2], &(*P)[3], &(*P)[4]);
```

```cpp
fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n", &P[0], &P[1], &P[2], &P[3], &P[4]);
```

And see that it simplified arguments of fscanf because we don't need to dereference pointer anymore.

Also, you can notice that call to `ReadFile` has a different argument:

```cpp
        float table[] = {1.0,2.0,4.0,8.0,10.0}; 

        ReadFile(table);
```

Right now it's just a table which implicitly casts to pointer to float.
So it will be the same as `ReadFile(&table[0]);`

The other way to pass arguments to fscanf is to use pointer arithmetic instead of arrays:

```cpp
fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n", P + 0, P + 1, P + 2, P + 3, P + 4);
```

Because `P + 1` is the same as `&P[1]`

Did I make it clear? I think not. But I tried :)

Comment: It works :) 
thank you for your good explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ReadFile(table);
```

because the compiler uses the address when you mention an array, so this passes the array address. You don't need `&` here.

So:

```
void ReadFile(float *P) {
```

because a "pointer to" can also be an "array of"

And so:

```
 fscanf(fp, "<p> %f %f %f %f %f\n", &P[0], &P[1], &P[2], &P[3], &P[4]);
```